# Can I create a file with functions only and import it in an App when using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this in react:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Applic from "./ColorAdder/Applic";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => <div style={styles}>Here I want to use my function and show results</div>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Can I create another file, containing only functions, not components, e.g. `getCurrentTime()` and use it in App.js?

How can I import it?

Comment: Why not, you can do that always

Comment: Consider using `export` with the function(s), either with named exports or default export. Then, you can import it on your component file like usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.
Example:

`getCurrentTime.js`:

```
export default () => {
   // your code...
}
```

`App.js`:

```
import getCurrentTime from './geTCurrentTime';
const time = getCurrentTime();
console.log(time);
```

In your sample `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Applic from "./ColorAdder/Applic";
import getCurrentTime from './geTCurrentTime';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => <div style={styles}>{getCurrentTime()}</div>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can like this ,

**export default somethingFunction = {} and in another file:

import {somethingFunction} from '/.path_to_your_file'**